# Add something automatically to the end of bash command

Tags: bash

I would like to know how to add something to the end of a specific bash command without having to type it out explicitly.

For example, I would like to be able to type:

```
$ mycommand argument
```

and the line will be submitted as:

```
$ mycommand argument &
```

I know how to set up an alias in my `.bashrc` (e.g. `alias command="command -i"`) which will let me add non-positional arguments but I can't figure out how add something to the end.

Comment: You can can write a shell script, make it executable `chmod +x filename` and place it into one of the directories in the execution path (`echo $PATH`). This is more related to system administration.

Comment: You can declare a function instead of an alias if you need more power.

Comment: Does this concerns one (or a few) specific commands, or every possible command?

Comment: A specific, pre-designated command. Updated question to be clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a shell function.

```
mycommand () {
  command mycommand "$@" &
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. The key for me was the use of the of the `command` command, otherwise it wasn't interpreting the '&' correctly.