# iTerm2 triggers always echo "Done" after every entry

Tags: bash, iterm2

I'm looking to use iTerm2's Trigger functionality to look for the word "Done" and then to add a notification to the notification center on my mac.

I have the trigger working, however I want to be even more lazy. Is there a way to add the following code `echo "Done"`after every entry into iTerm2 so I don't have to type it.

**Examples**

Entering

```
git pull
```

Would result in

```
git pull;echo "Done"
```

This would also need to work in command chains such as the following.

Entering

```
git pull;drush cc all
```

Would result in

```
git pull;drush cc all;echo "Done"
```

I found something similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41120235/add-something-automatically-to-the-end-of-bash-command), but I don't believe it answers what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a script, add it to path  so it can be called from everywhere like git a while loop with a condition, you can also use Case for this  or if flow :

while test $# -gt 0
do

## your stuff

done

maybe im over thinking it, but if you want to know when its actually "done", you would need to store $pid, and then wait for pid die and then echo done.

Comment: I don't write bash very often. Would be willing to explain what that while loop is doing. I don't understand what test is supposed to be in this example, but mainly I get lost at "$# -gt 0"... Sorry for the lack of knowledge.